# Induced mutation for fruit

Tags: plant-physiology, chromosome, plant-anatomy, meiosis, pollination

If we induce a plant to be polyploidy would that affect other parts of the plant, for example when the plant produces a pollen grain would it still be (n) or would it be different?

Comment: When and how are you inducing polyploidy? Keep in mind that some plants already are polyploid.